# Is it possible/fine to run Prometheus, Loki, Grafana outside of Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, prometheus, grafana-loki

In some project there are scaling and orchestration implemented using technologies of a local cloud provider, with no Docker & Kubernetes. But the project has poor logging and monitoring, I'd like to instal Prometheus, Loki, and Grafana for metrics, logs, and visualisation respectively. Unfortunately, I've found no articles with instructions about using Prometheus without K8s.

But is it possible? If so, is it a good way? And how to do this? I also know that Prometheus & Loki can automatically detect services in the K8s to extract metrics and logs, but will the same work for a custom orchestration system?

Comment: For the close-voters: I don't consider this Q opinion-based cuz possibility of smth is an objective thing, just like simplicity to set up and maintain is an engineering topic which can be compared and measured with other approaches (e.g. w/ K8s vs w/o K8s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't comment about Loki, but Prometheus is definitely doable.
Prometheus supports a number of service discovery mechanisms, k8s being just on of them. If you look at the [list of options](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) (the ones ending with _sd_config) you can see if your provider is there.
If it is not then a generic service discovery can be used. Maybe [DNS-based](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#dns_sd_config) discovery will work with your custom system? If not then with some glue code a [file based service discovery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config) will almost certainly work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'm running Prometheus, Loki etc. just fine in a AWS ECS cluster. It just requires a bit more configuration especially regarding service discovery (if you are not already using something like ECS Service Disovery or Hashicorp Consul)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do I understand correctly, that Loki has no need of service discovery because Promtail should be installed in each service to send logs automatically?

Comment: Yes you are correct. This is the way to go not only for "big" services running on distinct VMs but also Kubernetes for example (one Promtail for every node). In some cases there are also logging drivers / services that handle the transfer of logs from services to Loki. An example for this is the Docker logging driver

Comment: I've got the last Q for a clarification: in case of K8s, how the Promtail should be installed? As a separate service in the pod, or as a part of each service I want to log? Or even on hosts, outside of pods?

Comment: I'll just refer you to the official doc https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/installation/